# How to get the end offset information using Sarama admin?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

Is there a way to get log end offset information for a particular topic using Sarama ClusterAdmin? (without directly using a consumer)

I was able to get **current offset** information using Sarama admin using the ListConsumerGroupOffsets API but it only seems to include the current offset information and not the end offset information.

```
response, err := admin.ListConsumerGroupOffsets(consumerGroupID, map[string][]int32{
    topicName: topicPartitions,
})
```

I looked at other APIs available in Sarama ClusterAdmin but I'm not sure...

Is is possible to get the end offset information as well using the ClusterAdmin API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's  wrong with using consumer API to get the high watermark?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from https://gist.github.com/nilsmagnus/809c56201a9e17ee405c1255f0b71aca.  It doesn't use the CluserAdmin API specifically, but it seems to work.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
    "log"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.ClientID = "your-client-id"
    config.Consumer.Return.Errors = true

    brokers := []string{"localhost:9092"}

    client, clienterr := sarama.NewClient(brokers, config)
    if clienterr != nil {
        log.Fatal(clienterr)
    }

    defer client.Close()

    topics, topicerr := client.Topics()

    if topicerr != nil {
        log.Fatal(topicerr)
    }

    for _, topic := range topics {
        if strings.Contains(topic, "__consumer_offsets") {
            continue
        }

        partitions, partitionerr := client.Partitions(topic)

        if partitionerr != nil {
            log.Fatal(partitionerr)
        }

        for _, partition := range partitions {
            offset, offseterr := client.GetOffset(topic, partition, sarama.OffsetNewest)

            if offseterr != nil {
                log.Fatal(offseterr)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("Offset for topic %s at %v on partition %d is %d\n", topic, time.Now(), partition, offset)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587